# Laravel Validation Mimes Is checked While I have Set Required_if

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently validating a form with this rule validation

```
protected $rules = [
    'domain' => ['required','regex:/([A-z]|\d+|\-)+(.com)$/'],
    'domain' => ['required','regex:/([A-z]|\d+|\-|\.)+(.com|.co.id)$/'],
    'logo' => ['required'],
    'customLogo' => 'required_if:logo,custom|max:4096|mimes:png,svg',
];
```

I have set that it is required if logo value 'custom' and it was null but it is still validating the mimes which cause error.

I am using Livewire form validation with this method

```
$input = $this->validate();
```

I really appreciate any answer

Comment: `.` should be escaped in all parts of regex. `A-z` also allows more than `a-z` and `A-Z`. `([A-z]|\d+|\-)` could be converted to `[-a-zA-Z\d]` presuming only alpha characters are intended.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `nullable` rule to indicate that the customLogo field can also be null (or empty).

By using the rule

```
'customLogo' => 'required_if:logo,custom|nullable|max:4096|mimes:png,svg'
```

When the `customLogo` is `null` or not sent but the value of `logo` is "custom", then the `required` validation will run. However, if the value of `logo` is other than "custom" and the `customLogo` is `null`, the validation will pass.

Also, it would be better if you are using the [`prepareForValidation`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method for this type of case of FormRequest as it will help to filter out the data and get properly formatted data in the controller.
Something like:

```
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $customLogo = $this->post('logo') === 'custom' ? $this->input('customLogo') : null;
    $this->merge(['customLogo' => $customLogo]);
}
```

This will help to make sure that `customLogo` is always null even if the file was uploaded when using `$request->validated()` when the value of `logo` is not "custom"

Answer (score 0):

Use following method, if logo has not null and value is custome than add the validation rules.

```
if (isset($request->logo) && $request->logo == 'custom') {
  $rules['customLogo'] = 'required|max:4096|mimes:png,svg';
}
```

or you use alternative method,

```
protected $rules = [
    'domain' => ['required','regex:/([A-z]|\d+|\-)+(.com)$/'],
    'domain' => ['required','regex:/([A-z]|\d+|\-|\.)+(.com|.co.id)$/'],
    'logo' => ['required'],
    'customLogo' => 'required_if:logo,custom|max:4096|mimes:png,svg',
];

if (in_array('custom', $request->input('logo', []))) {
    $rules['customLogo'] = 'required|max:4096|mimes:png,svg';
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

This will help to prevent mimes error which cause.